# Want to Setup Digital Free Library, Will I Still be Able to ssh?

Tags: wifi, ssh, pi-zero-w, hotspot

My Pi is headless and connected to the wifi network (It's a Raspberry Pi Zero W).  If I set it up as a Digital Free Library (As per this link https://learn.adafruit.com/digital-free-library/what-youll-need), will I no longer be able to ssh into the pi wirelessly, as the wifi card is occupied?  Since it is a Zero it doesn't have an ethernet port, I'm not sure how to set it up so I can ssh into it whilst it's acting as a wifi hotspot?

Comment: a wifi hotspot still has an IP address that you can connect to

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will still be able to make SSH connections after setting up your RPi ZeroW as a Digital Free Library. The SSH server in your RPi is run from a different "port" (port 22) than the library (probably port 80). No problem!

Here's a short explanation of [how ports and interfaces relate to each other](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/52617/tcp-ip-port)